# How to prioritize BCS content at the top of search results?

Tags: 2013, search, bcs, ranking

I have a requirement in a SharePoint 2013 environment to push all BCS items to the top of the search results. I have played with the weight/context groups as well as result source sorting, but have not gotten the results I am looking for. The goal is to allow SharePoint to prioritize the search results ranks based on the OOTB ranking model, but push all BCS items to the top of the results. Is this possible without creating a custom ranking model?

Comment: One thing I left out is that the document text (i.e. "body" managed property) appears on the surface to be taking precendance. So, all documents show up before BCS items even if I create BCS managed properties with a lower managed property content/weight than "body".

Answer (score 0):

Look into using search scopes or metadata.

www.codeproject.com/Tips/363642/Hiding-Title-Bar-Navigation-Breadcrumb-section-in

You will most likely want to have two results sections. That might make it easier. One will query the BCS data and will be at the top. The 2nd will search your other content.